# Android Game development - Imageview automatically shrinks at screen edge

Tags: android, resize, imageview, shrink

I have a bunch of dynamically created ImageViews representing different objects in a game, which is working fine. However if any Image reaches the edge of the screen, it shrinks. Looks like android is attempting to create a smooth transition, but this is not wanted.

I found another thread with the same issue here: [Animation Drawable gets automatically shrinks at the corners ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918634/animation-drawable-gets-automatically-shrinks-at-the-corners), however his solution does not work for me, it only enhances the issue as it starts shrinking once the margin hits the screen edge.

This is my code:

```
final LayoutParams _updated_params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

_updated_params.setMargins((int)m_x, (int)m_y, 0, 0);

m_image.setLayoutParams(_updated_params);</code>
```

Where m_x/m_y is the absolute position of the image and m_image is an ImageView instance.

Does anyone know how I can turn off this automatic resizing?

Answer (score 0):

Add setScaleType

```
m_image.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use setScaleType

```
m_image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```