# My images shrink when they are at the edge of my display screen - Android

Tags: android, imageview, scaletype

I have small animating images in my android app that randomly bounce across the screen, I notice whenever any of these images touche the edge they shrink down and as to not have the image expand past the edge of the screen

the only other post I have seen that addresses this issue is this one but using setScaleType does not fix the issue for me
[Android Game development - Imageview automatically shrinks at screen edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298549/android-game-development-imageview-automatically-shrinks-at-screen-edge)

Using img.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY); makes it expand to its proper width if close to the top or bottom of the screen and has it at its proper height if close to the left or right of the screen but if the position of the image has it where the height extends past the top or bottom edge the height of the image shrinks to the point so that all of the image stays within the screen and doesnt crop out like I want it to do.

How do I fix this so that my images remain the correct size at all times and just crops out the part of the image that extends past the edge of the screen

Any incite would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: try placing your imageview inside layout's like framelayout relative layout etc they provide z index placement and a view is allowed to go out of screen boundary I dont know if this helps you though